# Initial page load slow using Tornado server and Apache2 for SSL reverse proxy

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, reverse-proxy, tornado

I'm experiencing long delays (generally minutes, but sometimes the page never loads) for my website ([en-real.com](https://en-real.com)) if the site is being accessed by a new user (browser). If the new browser refreshes the page, the content is displayed and everything is fine. Interestingly, when a new user causes this lag, it also hangs the connections of old users. If any user hits 'refresh', all users get their content loaded properly.

I can re-produce this behavior on Chrome and Firefox in private mode. In private mode, if a request hasn't been made in more than 30 or so minutes, the request lags.

The content is being served by Tornado listening on port 8700. I have a reverse proxy run by Apache2 set up to forward requests from ports 443 and 80 to port 8700. I have a feeling the reverse proxy might have something to do with the behavior, but have no idea what to test. Or perhaps it could have to do with SSL certs being loaded?